# jenkins build github pull requests for few projects

Tags: github, jenkins, build, pull-request

we are using GitHub pull request builder plugin to check PRs before merge it works just fine. But we have more than one project and most PRs affect a few projects in the same time, so my question is there any way to build PRs for few projects if project 1 depends on project 2. I believe there should be solution but I can't find any.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Multi-SCM-plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multiple+SCMs+Plugin) for pulling all the repository into the same workspace.

Comment: Thank, I can same way clone needed repo with shell script. Im looking for some better solution, but maybe I should just workaround it this way...

Comment: Well, you can perform the checkout of the multiple git repos as a script without the need of the plugin. In that way you can adjust the script to your needs.